# Infinite loops in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

```
while ($my_query = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select table2.ctg_id from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.game_id = table1.id where table1.id = $id"))) 
{
    echo $my_query['data'];
}
```

When i try this query on navicat, i take;
2
3

but in '.php' page, query go infinite loop.

Comment: Whats the output of PHP?

Comment: Well, from what I see, you are executing mysql_query() in the while condition, which always succeeds. You need to do the query previously, and then use mysql_fetch_array with those results in the while condition

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the status report on your current development efforts. Did you have **question** you wanted to ask? (Q: For you next post, are you going to give us a report on how to cause a fork bomb on Unix?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're running the query anew in each loop. You need to save the result of the query then fetch an array from that in each loop:

```
$result = mysql_query("select table2.ctg_id from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.game_id = table1.id where table1.id = $id");
while ($my_query = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $my_query['data'];
}
```

Also the mysql_ extension is deprecated. Don't forget to update your project to mysqli or preferably PDO soon.